# Can I duplicate a data in hdfs (hadoop)

Tags: file, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, replication

I am new in hadoop (v 2.6.0)
I work in my thesis with genetic algorithm in hadoop (Linux).
My problem :

1:I want to duplicate the file input (text) in hdfs location for all the slaves (not partitioned the file)
for example I have a file (200 Mb) I want to sent all the file to the slaves.(200 for slave 1 and 200 for slave 2 ...etc)
is that possible?if that is possible what is the keys to doing that?

2: second question:I have 2 slaves and one master ... when I start is my program by default execute in all slaves? or hadoop decide what slave will execute the program?if hadoop decide that how i make My program executable in all slaves without exception?i hope that is possible.
because when my program launched I see that it is executed just in slave 2 (not the slave 1.)

#### Edit 1 with text from his comment-answer

thank you for this detaills my data cannot grow arbitrarily large: if i inderstend you right ...well if i have in my data 200 individuals ...it stile 200 indivual with this algorithme...

inside the algorithme if i specific 30 chromosomes .well the algorithme will excute in every node with 200 individuals (in the data base in input file) and with 30 chromosom inside the execution...this parameters will specifie by me before starting my code. they are not a parameter that will be grow arbitrarily large in my algorithme.

can you give me more detaill about InputFormat to start my algorithme)

#### Edit 2 with text from his second comment-answer

[In this document](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0086.pdf) you can find in c:related work in this part said: `The existent literature proposes some parallel version of GAs using the MapReduce paradigm. The first is an extension, by adding a second Reducer, of MapReduce named “MRPGA” [6] based on .Net. In this implementation a coordinator client manages the executions of the parallel GA iterations. The chosen model is the island model in which each participating node computes GAs operations for a portion of the entire population. In the first phase, each Mapper node receives its own portion of population and computes the fitness value for each of its individuals. The Reducer nodes of the first reduce phase receive the individuals of the correspondent island and apply the selection function. The final Reducer computes the global selection and the other following GAs functions.`

That only detaills in this documentabout this approach. the portion of population here is mean the number of chromosoms.(a group of chromosoms named population if you decide de work with 2000 chromosoms and 5 slaves then just specifie 400 chromosoms in the code and every slave will work with just 400 (400*5 =2000)...that s my point.. because if you specifie a 2000 for one node this is very much and take a huge timefor the fitness.you inderstood?the real data that i will partionne it is the chromosoms not the data of input file ,and i want to use a huge number of chromosoms because when you use a big number of chromosoms you will get the approximative solution that u need.

Comment: Please clarify your question. I think you might be approaching this question with an MPI frame of mind. Hadoop splits a file up across data nodes to parallelize the work. You don't send the data anywhere, the framework does it for you. What your asking sounds like you want the exact same data (not chunks of input data) worked on simultaneously by multiple nodes. Is that right?
For the master slave question, those aren't Hadoop terms. You might be thinking of the submitting node and data nodes? If so, the submitting node does no work other than the submitting. The data nodes do all the work.

Comment: hello Mr keegan thanks very much for your interesting about my question.
for the first question  is yes like you  inderstood exactly ...is there any way to do that because hadoop by default devise the input data ...
for the second question :
the slaves nodes execute the same code yes ...but i remark that not all the slaves do the execution , just few slaves (for exemple you have 7 slaves but just 3 do the execution because hadoop see that the others not necessary for execution?i am right?how i force the execution in all the nodes ? i hope that my concepts about that it is true @Keegan

Comment: One more question: Why do you want all the data sent to all the nodes? Do you expect the same or different answers from each of the nodes in the map() portion? Is it possible for your algorithm to operate on a subset of the data at a time?

Comment: thanks again i apprecite your answers
well the algorithm genetic can't  work with portion of data ... i will excute my algorithm genetic in all the nodes and every node send a solution.

the reducer node chose the best solution between all the solutionns sended.

excatly:the function of fitness in algorithm gentic shoud work with all data not just a portion ..if it work just with a portion the solution will be inccorected (this is the standard of agorithme genetic).i hope that you inderstend me. @Keegan

Comment: i expect a different answer for every node (the concept of algorithme genetic work with the aleatory ) .

Comment: Is the 200MB 1 record? So 2 records will be like 400MB, or could a single record grow to 400MB or larger?

Comment: hello sir..

i just give a example ... in the begening i will travel just with a data base(the input file) with a 1.9 MB...but if my algorithm working with this data base in all nodes and i get a acceptable results .. i will use another data base(larger)...and i think that is a hard because hadoop work with 64 MB in each block.

Comment: i read the whole file as single record.(so the map not read the file line by line).

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop doesn't really do what you want it to do.  There might be a way to define your own [InputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.html) (and probably override some other classes as well) to force it to do what you want, but I can't really recommend that.

The [map()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28parallel_pattern%29) part of [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) fundamentally relies on being able to decompose a problem "into independent subtasks, requiring no communication/synchronization between the subtasks".  If your problem has input data that's a single record that can grow arbitrarily large, and cannot be broken up, MapReduce is fundamentally the wrong conceptual approach because you're not doing any decomposition.

The way I'd think this could be decomposed (if you're speaking of the normal evolutionary algorithm) is to break it up by record (individual, in this case), and your file would be a collection of records.  You could then split the file up by record.  Depending on your file format, you can create an `InputFormat`, if necessary, so that it knows how to split the file up.  Potentially this will result in rather large records, so you may want to tune your block size to be around the average size of your records, for better distribution.

It looked like others did their generations either as separate jobs or in the reducer, and not in the mapper as you are proposing.  You might read these papers on the topic.

- [A Parallel Genetic Algorithm Based on Hadoop MapReduce for the
  Automatic Generation of JUnit Test Suite - Linda Di Geronimo, Filomena Ferrucci, Alfonso Murolo, Federica Sarro](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/F.Sarro/resource/papers/C2.pdf)
- [Parallelization of genetic algorithms using Hadoop Map/Reduce - Dino Kečo, Abdulhamit Subasi](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Abdulhamit_Subasi/publication/258858471_Parallelization_of_genetic_algorithms_using_Hadoop_MapReduce/links/0046352945f2358517000000.pdf)
- [A Framework for Genetic Algorithms Based on Hadoop - Filomena Ferrucci, M-Tahar Kechadi, Pasquale Salza, Federica Sarro](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0086.pdf)
- [Scaling Genetic Algorithms Using MapReduce - Verma, A.; Llora, X.; Goldberg, D.E.; Campbell, R.H.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5362925)

Alternatively, you could use an existing framework.  [Apache Mahout Cookbook, Chapter 10](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/apache-mahout-cookbook/9781849518024/ch10.html) describes how the [Watchmaker Framework](http://watchmaker.uncommons.org/) can be used in [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) (Hadoop's machine learning library) for evolutionary computation.

You may also find that [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) better suits your needs since it has better iterative computation since it keeps more in memory.  There's even native support for evolution algorithms [being built](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3830) for their machine learning library ([MLlib](http://spark.apache.org/mllib/)).

I hope this doesn't ruin your thesis.

Comment: hello again ... thank you for this detaills 
my data cannot grow arbitrarily large:
if i inderstend you right ...well if i have in my data 200 individuals ...it stile 200 indivual with this algorithme...

inside the algorithme if i specific 30 chromosomes .well the algorithme will excute in every node with 200 individuals (in the data base in input file) and with 30 chromosom inside the execution...this parameters will specifie by me before starting my code.
they are not a parameter that will be grow arbitrarily large in my algorithme.

Comment: can you give me more detaill about InputFormat to start my algorithme...(well i find more articles that work with my stratigie).

Comment: I don't see how they could have implemented the algorithm in the way you're considering.  If you provide specifics about what they did, and I'll tell you how to configure the framework to replicate the results.

Comment: The paper clearly describes mapping over individuals, as I suggested
`map : (individual, NULL) → (individualF, NULL)`
They are not processing the same individual on more than one data node (which is good, because it avoids the issues I described).  But you're correct, the iterations are also done in the mapper.  They seem to be suggesting using [ChainMapper](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainMapper.html) for subsequent iterations.

Comment: yes the iteratons will generate a differents chromosomes(you can named it a individual) arbitrarily ...(the number is fixed before excution).
but the chromosome individuel is different for the individuel in the data base(the individuals in the text inputs used just just in phas of fitness function)..but the chromosomoes indivudals is usedin all th process

Comment: well i will not do the same idea .. so the only think that i needed to complet my work as i want and i am a sure that is given a result when i find a way to send all the file not a portions of input..if thats possible to given me atleast a key words to dowing that because the InputFormat it is very large domain ,I dont think that i will find the way to do this